# Using keyboard to navigate the OS X terminal scrollback buffer

Tags: bash, emacs, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

I hate using the mouse.  When working in the OS X terminal, sometimes I want to navigate to a line in the bash shell a few rows up, copy a word or two. For this I always end up using the mouse.   Any solution for this? Perhaps the terminal supports a key combination that puts it in to navigation/select/copy mode, where I can use the usual C-F, C-B, C-N and C-P keys.

Comment: What is the name of the shell you are using?

Comment: bash, like 99% of people :)

Comment: here's a common workflow of mine:

    $ git grep -i 'send me'
    app/views/devise/passwords/new.html.erb:<%= f.submit 'Send me reset password instructions', :class => 'btn full' %>
    $ vi <NOW I WANT TO MOVE UP BY ONE LINE, SELECT SOME WORDS AND PASTE IT HERE>

Comment: You mean, you want to select some words from the *output* of the `grep` command? (Hint: If you want to make examples *readable* to non-telepaths, *edit them into your question*. Comments are useless for that.)

Answer (score 0):

If you feel comfortable with `Vi` key combinations, you can use this command to switch to `vi-mode` and use key strokes:

```
$ set -o vi
```

Or use `C-xC-e` to open current line in your `$EDITOR`.